# Tapping label crashes app

Tags: c#, email, xamarin, label, call

I don't know what is wrong with my code. Can someone check my code for fail/errors? I am trying to make a list with contacts. and when I tap the email, I want to send a mail to the address I tap. the same with phone number. [When I tap Email or Tlfnr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1ZID.png)

My xaml.CS code:

```
    private void OnEmailTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var emailMessenger = CrossMessaging.Current.EmailMessenger;
        if (emailMessenger.CanSendEmail)
        {
            emailMessenger.SendEmail(to: ((Label)sender).Text); 
        }
    }
```

My Xaml code:

```
                                <StackLayout x:Name="EmailTapped">
                                    <Label x:Name="OnEmailTapped" Text="{Binding Email}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Medium" />

                                    <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnEmailTapped" CommandParameter="{Binding Email}"/>
                                    </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                </StackLayout>
```

My Contacts:

```
namespace App3
{
public class Kontakter
{
    public string Fuldenavn { get; set; }
    public string Tlfnr { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public List<Kontakter> GetKontakter()
    {
        List<Kontakter> kontakter = new List<Kontakter>
    {
        new Kontakter
        {
            Fuldenavn = "bacon (ANSE)",
            Email = "Random@gmail.com",
            Tlfnr = 12345678,
        },
        new Kontakter
        {
            Fuldenavn = "Anja (ANBI)",
            Email = "Random@hotmail.dk",
            Tlfnr = 87654321,
        },
        new Kontakter
        {
            Fuldenavn = "Benn (BMR)",
            Email = "Random@hotmail.com",
            Tlfnr = 12876534,
        },
        new Kontakter
        {
            Fuldenavn = "Christian (CBE)",
            Email = "Nothing@gmail.com",
            Tlfnr = 18273645,
        },
    };
        return kontakter;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: before we do your checking and debugging for you, when you run this what errors do you get? What is your result, what is your expected result?

Comment: The problem is, i dont have any errors before i start the program. but when i tap any email or phone nummber it crashes. like on the picture. @CodeWarrior

Comment: that error message is pretty clear - the cast is failing.  You need to figure out what the actual type of sender is, apparently Label is not correct.

Comment: As others have stated the error message tells you exactly what is wrong, you are casting to a label when that is an invalid cast...

Comment: What can you do to fix it? @MartynWeber

Comment: @Noobcoder I have posted an answer

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, it stoped crashing when i removed

```
if (emailMessenger.CanSendEmail)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is cast the sender as a control.

```
Control castControl = (Control)sender
```

Or set a break point and assign the value to a random var and hover the sender object

[image]

And then do a cast to the specific type that is shown in the break point hover

I think the sender is probably the `TapGestureRecognizer` rather than `Label`

Although mine shows as a `Label` it is just to give you an idea of how you could find the `type` of the sender object

Comment: Can you try to give me some code to work with. i am not sure what to do @Martyn Weber

Comment: I have given you the code, what you need to do is assign the sender object to a variable and set a breakpoint, when it hits that breakpoint you can hover over the sender object and it will tell you what the object type is, and then you cast it as that object type.